# How to read output from git pull --stat with colors into variable

Tags: git, bash, colors, io-redirection

How can I read stdout from `git pull` **with colors** into a bash variable?

Escaped sequences from `ls --color=always` are easily read into `$output`:

```
$ output=$(ls --color=always)
$ echo -e "$output"
```

But not from `git pull --stat`:

```
$ git config color.ui always
$ output=$(git pull --stat <repository> <refspec>)
$ echo -e "$output"
```

In other words, how can I trick `git pull` into thinking that it is not going to output into a variable? This does not work: `$ env TERM=xterm-color git pull --stat`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your config variable, it should be `color.ui`, singular, not `colors.ui`.
On my system with git version 1.7.10 it then works as expected.

**Update:** see screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You mean, you were able to capture the green-red characteres too? Thanks for noticing the typo in the question. I still can't do it.

Comment: Note you don't need the `-e` in the `echo` but should be harmless. Added screenshot to answer. Don't know why it doesn't work for you.